# NextAuth Typescript integration with nextjs13

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, next-auth

This is the first time I use, NextAuth, and with the major changes of Nextjs 13. I have no idea how to set up nextauth on my project.
I have read the documentation [here](https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/typescript)

Somehow not sure how to set it up for nextjs 13. How can I make it work?
[...nextauth].ts file setup

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth"
import FacebookProvider from "next-auth/providers/facebook";

export const authOptions = {
  // Configure one or more authentication providers
  providers: [
   FacebookProvider({
    clientId: process.env.FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: process.env.FACEBOOK_CLIENT_SECRET
  }),
  
  ],
}

export default NextAuth(authOptions)
```

Errors so far:
**Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)
oauth.d.ts(83, 5): The expected type comes from property 'clientId' which is declared here on type 'OAuthUserConfig'**

layout.tsx page

```
import { Outfit } from "@next/font/google";

import "../styles/globals.css";
import Header from "./components/Header/Header";
import { SessionProvider } from "next-auth/react";

// Outfit Font
const outfit = Outfit();
export default function RootLayout({
  children,
  pageProps: { session, ...pageProps },
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <SessionProvider session={session}>
      <html>
        <head></head>

        <body lang="en" className={outfit.className}>
          <Header />
          {children}
        </body>
      </html>
    </SessionProvider>
  );
}
```

In the layout file it tells me that Property 'pageProps' does not exist on type '{ children: ReactNode; }

I would appreciate any help to setup this up.

Answer (score 1):

To use next-auth with nextjs13, first wrap your mail layout into a session provider (SessionProvider has to be called in a client component, so either make your layout component a client one, or create a provider as shown in Christian Pham answer):

```js
"use client";

import "./global.css";

import { SessionProvider } from "next-auth/react";

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="fr">
      <body>
        <SessionProvider>
        {children}
        </SessionProvider>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

Then you can access session in both server side components and API routes handler using getServerSession:

```js
import { authOptions } from "../../../../pages/api/auth/[...nextauth]"

// Server Component example
export default async function AdventureEditorPage({ params }) {
    const session = await getServerSession(authOptions);
    if (!session) {
        redirect("/");
    }
    return (<>OK<>);
}
```

```
// Route handler example
export async function PUT(request: Request) {
    const session = await getServerSession(authOptions);
    if (!session) {
        return new NextResponse(null, { status: 403 });
    }
    //...
}
```

And client side components using useSession:

```js
"use client";

import { useSession } from "next-auth/react";

export function Header() {
    const { data: session } = useSession();

    return (
        <>
            {session && <>Logged in<>}
        </>
    );
}
```

signIn and signOut method husage have not changed.

For more information, I think next-auth will soon be updated for nextjs13.
You can also take a look at my project https://github.com/mathieuguyot/adventures which is using next-auth for both server and client side components and also experimental app directory.

About your first error, typescript indicates that process.env.FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID may be not set.
You can a check to overpass the error:

```js
process.env.FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID ? process.env.FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID : ""
```

Answer (score 1):

1- One way is to create `randomFileName.d.ts` and add this

```
declare namespace NodeJS {
  interface ProcessEnv {
    FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID: string;
    FACEBOOK_CLIENT_SECRET:string
  }
}
```

then include `randomFileName.d.ts` to tsconfig.json `include` property

```
"include": ["next-env.d.ts","randomFileName.d.ts" "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx", ".next/types/**/*.ts"],
```

2- return those env variables in a function

```
const getFacebookVariables= ( ) : {clientId: string; clientSecret: string} => {
  const clientId = process.env.FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID;
  const clientSecret = process.env.FACEBOOK_CLIENT_SECRET;
  if (!clientId || clientId.length === 0) {
    throw new Error("No clientId");
  }

  if (!clientSecret || clientSecret.length === 0) {
    throw new Error("No clientSecret");
  }
  return { clientId, clientSecret };
}
```

then when you use them

```
 FacebookProvider({
    clientId: getFacebookVariables().clientId,
    clientSecret: getFacebookVariables().clientSecret
  }),
```

Comment: Can you help me with this question please?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76300196/nextauth-error-missing-nextauth-api-route-error-in-next-js-13-app-route

Answer (score 0):

I think, you should create providers.js like:

```
'use client'

import { useState } from 'react'
import { SessionProvider } from 'next-auth/react'

export const Providers = ({ children }) => {

  return (
    <SessionProvider>
          {children}
    </SessionProvider>
  )
}
```

then wrap it in RootLayout:

```
import './globals.css'
import { Providers } from './providers'

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">

      <head />
      <body><Providers>{children}</Providers></body>
    </html>
  )
}
```