# NextAuth Error 'MISSING_NEXTAUTH_API_ROUTE_ERROR' in Next.js 13 (app route)

Tags: next.js, next-auth, next.js13, app-route

I'm using NextAuth version 4.22.1 with Next.js version 13.4.

I'm getting this error 'MISSING_NEXTAUTH_API_ROUTE_ERROR'. My auth provider is Auth0.
I've followed all of the steps required as mentioned in the [guidelines](https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/example).

I've folder structure like this:
`src/app/api/auth/[...nextAuth]/route.ts`


Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In my case, changing the capital letter A from `[...nextAuth]` in small letter like this`[...nextauth]` solved my problem.

Comment: This was the exact issue I had.

Answer (score 8):

The problem is most likely due to with dots in the `[...nextauth]` folder name which needs to be `...` instead of `…` as mentionned on this issue from the github:

https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/issues/7632

It solved the problem for me.